# Java - Improving iteration through large String List

Tags: java, performance, iteration

I have to parse files which has around 50000 lines and has to iterate through each line, parse, create a List and save to database. Initially I thought the time taken is because of reading the file. But the file is actually read within a second. But the parsing of data takes long time.

```
public static final String  record      =   "dlrCode,partNumber,5,0.00,5000.00,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0,0.00,0";
    public static final String COMMA        =   ",";
    public static final String QUOTES       =   "\"";
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING =   "";

    public static void main(String[] args){


        List<String> recordsList            =   new ArrayList<String>();
        Date time                           =   new Date();
        Part partVO                         =   null;
        PartHistory partHistoryVO           =   null;
        List<PartHistory> partHistoryList   =   null;
        List<Part> partsList                =   new ArrayList<Part>();
        int splitLength                     =   0;
        Calendar cal                        =   Calendar.getInstance();
        int historySplitCount               =   0;
        int monthCountReverse               =   0; 

        //add 20000 records to list
        for(int i=0; i<20000; i++){
            recordsList.add(record);
        }
        System.out.println("Added in "+((new Date()).getTime() - time.getTime()) +" ms");

        //reset time
        time                            =   new Date();

        //parse records
        for(String sCurrentLine :  recordsList){
            partVO = new Part();
            partHistoryList =   new ArrayList<PartHistory>();

            //Parsing inventory information
            partVO.setDealerCode(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[0]);
            partVO.setPartNumber(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[1]);
            partVO.setDmsMfId(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[2]);
            partVO.setQtyOnHand(Math.round(Float.parseFloat(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[3])));
            partVO.setDealerNet(Float.parseFloat(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[4]));

            //Parsing history information
            //starting from the 6th record as the first 5 records are used above
            historySplitCount   =   5;

            //to subtract one month from current date
            monthCountReverse   =   -1; 

            splitLength =   sCurrentLine.split(COMMA).length;

            while(splitLength>=(historySplitCount+1)){

                partHistoryVO   =   new PartHistory();
                //subtract one month from current date
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthCountReverse);
                partHistoryVO.setMonth(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
                partHistoryVO.setYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                partHistoryVO.setLineHitsMonthly(Math.round(Float.parseFloat(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[historySplitCount])));
                historySplitCount++;

                partHistoryVO.setQuantity(Math.round(Float.parseFloat(sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[historySplitCount])));
                historySplitCount++;
                partHistoryList.add(partHistoryVO);
            }
            partVO.setHistoryList(partHistoryList);

            partsList.add(partVO);
        }
        System.out.println("Iterated in "+((new Date()).getTime() - time.getTime()) +" ms");
    }
```

**Output**

```
Added in 15 ms  
Iterated in 12823 ms
```

Can the iteration time be improved and brought under atleast 5 seconds?

Comment: You could do it using parallel streams in Java 8.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the application uses Java 6 and cannot be changed. Any suggestions with Java 6?

Comment: Why are you splitting the line every time?  Could you not split the line on comma, put that in a single array, then use that array for the scope of that `while`?

Comment: Use `ExecutorService` to add concurrency then.

Comment: Yep, spliting 9 times. Once would be enough.

Comment: Are you really just using a static string? You mentioned reading from a file, is the static string in this just an example?

Comment: Also, to @LuiggiMendoza point, you could parallel the execution.  Read in all the rows into a Queue of String, then have multiple threads pop a String off the queue and work it.  This way you are maximizing CPU.  You should be able to do that with and JVM, by the way.  Maybe look at Java 6's `Executor`, which has several implementations like `ThreadPoolExecutor` and such.

Comment: If your times are based off creating a list of static streams, then what you're seeing is JIT (Just In Time) in action. Java doesn't actually create that list one item at a time, it sees what you're going for an creates the list on the fly... If you're reading from a file though it's a different story and I feel like 15 ms is way too fast.

Comment: This is just an example for understanding. The actual file parsing involves more rules. Yes, adding to list takes only between 15ms to 30ms(different runs) for the above example.

Comment: Thanks @CodeChimp and others for the suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling
`sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)`
several times in your code. Make a
`final String[]`
variable the first time you call it in the loop and use that instead thereafter and it'll get that many times faster.

Comment: Great! came down to 2 second! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each line, you call the split() function multiple times, sCurrentLine.split(COMMA)[0],

a better way is to split it once and store into an array

```
String[] elements = sCurrentLine.split(COMMA);
dealerCode = elements[0];
partNumber = elements[1];
```

FYI, to count how much time spent, you can also use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, this does not need to create a new Date instance :)

```
long timeStarts = System.currentTimeMillis();
//loop goes here
long timeTook = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStarts;
```